# slide show not works in downloaded site

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I've built a site http://ucemeche.weebly.com , Now I want to transfer it on other server. http://Weebly.com provides a function to download whole site in zip format that I've done.
But problem is when I am browsing that downloaded site the slide shows, photo gallery etc are not working in as working in live site. Perhaps it is related to java script.

Why is it happening ? What is the solution ?

Comment: To download a whole site you need paths. If the paths are dynamic they are not resolved

Answer (score 1):

Check the paths of the javascripts. You might be missing some scripts or you do not include them properly.

Check the error console in your browser. Most likely it will show you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to change the paths to the images in the html file

the paths will be something like:

```
"2\/1\/2\/5\/56254238\/3375189.png"
```

change them to:

```
"..\/folder name where your files are\/uploads\/2\/1\/2\/5\/56254238\/3375189.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

This was three years ago, so perhaps this is a late answer.  There is a hosted file slideshow-jq.js.  In it, there is a function largeURL(photo).

Copy that slideshow-jq.js into the root of your zip, and edit the file:

`url = '/uploads/' + url.replace(/^\/uploads\//, '');`

Remove the leading / in front of uploads.

Now, update your page and look for this line:
`<script src="http://cdn2.editmysite.com/js/site/main.js?buildTime=1234"></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn1.editmysite.com/editor/libraries/slideshow-jq.js?buildTime=1234'></script>`

Or something like that.  Change the src to the local file, "./slideshow-jq.js"

That corrects the issue.